# What does the jQuery scrollTop value mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on some jquery code using the scrollTop method to implement an infinite scroll (please, don't suggest jQuery plugins, I know they exist) and I don't quite understand what this value means.

Given this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ve8s5fdx/

```
<div id="outter">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div id="scroll"></div>
```

```css
#outter {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y:auto;
}

.inner {
  height: 150px;
  width: 50%;
  border: dashed black 2px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

It makes sense that the value is 0 when the scrollbar is at the very top of the element, but why "208" when it's at the bottom ? The `#outter` div is 100px high, its content a bit more than 300px.

Comment: `scrollTop` is the number of pixels that the window is scrolled down from the top of the document

Comment: so why is it not > 300px when being at the bottom ? We've scrolled down the whole content, which is > 300px high ? That's the point I don't understand

Comment: It depends on how tall your `window` is. If window is `300px` in height and the document is `400px` then the highest value `scrollTop` can possibly have is `100`

Comment: Because it measures it from the top of your screen and not the bottom of your screen. Your divs are both 154 px high including the border and together they make 308px. considering your 100px height div scrolled all the way to the bottom the top of that div is 208px and the bottom of the div is at 308px

Comment: thanks ! Makes sense now ! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What @Rory McCrossan said.
If you scrolled down 100px, the .scrollTop will display 100.
The `scrollTop` will measure the space between the window and the element. So it doesn't matter how high your element is, it will always be the space above it that counts.

Since your `.inner` is missing the css-rule `box-sizing: border-box;` the border will be added outside the div, and it's 2px wide. Which in your case means that every `.inner` element is 154px high. You have 2 of those, so the content of `.outer` is 308px.

Your `.outer`-element is 100px high so 100px will always be visible. So when your window is scrolled to the very bottom, the scrollTop displays 308px - 100px = 208px.

If you change your `.outer` to the height of 50px, the scrollTop will display 258px when scrolled to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

[$.scrollTop](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/):

> The vertical scroll position is the same as the number of pixels that
>   are hidden from view above the scrollable area. If the scroll bar is
>   at the very top, or if the element is not scrollable, this number will
>   be 0.

Inspecting your fiddle, you can see that your two `.inner`s have a combined height of 308 px. Your outer (scrolling) div is 100 px tall.

So your `.scrollTop()`, *the number of pixels that are hidden from view above the scrollable area* is `total inner height - visible height`, or 208 px.